# Animating an image sprite using jQuery Animate in steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am attempting to code an image sprite using jQuery and am wondering if it's possible to animate in steps instead of linear. Basically, I attempted using CSS3 animations, but IE9 is a requirement and I could not get the CSS3 animations to function correctly in IE.

I have a sprite which has 12 frames, each frame being 280px X 280px. I would like to use jQuery to animate the sprite on mouseover and mouseout in steps instead of sliding the background image in a linear fashion.

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="window"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.window {
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    background: url("http://s27.postimg.org/neu6mvztf/single_hung_door.png");
}
```

JS:

```
$(".window").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'background-position-x': '0',
            'background-position-y': '-3080px'
        }, 1500, 'linear');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'background-position-x': '0',
            'background-position-y': '0'
        }, 1500, 'linear');
    }
);
```

[JSFiddle with sample of desired effect](http://jsfiddle.net/3akjqfy2/1/)

Would it be possible to accomplish this in this way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't the most elegant code, but basically, I think you need an animating loop running continuously that only shifts the frame animation by one frame every x milliseconds.  The fiddle you had continuously animates the whole strip in a linear fashion.  Forked jsFiddle link below.

```
var currentY = 0;
var isAnimating = false;
var $window = $('.window');
var windowWidth = 280;
var frameRateMs = 60;

function updateWindow() {
    if (isAnimating) {
        $window.css({'background-position-y': currentY + 'px'});
        currentY -= windowWidth;
        if (currentY == -3080) {
            windowWidth = -280;
        } else if (currentY == 0) {
            windowWidth = 280;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(updateWindow, frameRateMs);
}

$window.hover(function() {
    isAnimating = true;
}, function() {
    isAnimating = false;
});

updateWindow();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/64nu4h4w/10/

Comment: Very nice!! This is already above and beyond what I was expecting, but would it be possible to make it so that on mouseover the window only animates once(upwards) and then stops and then on mouseout it animates once(downwards) and stops?

Comment: Well, it would go something like this one.  There is one flaw though, if you how in/out too quick, the order of the open close will be reversed.  I leave it as an exercise to the reader on how to fix that.  http://jsfiddle.net/bradleybossard/6k33y37a/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a libray named velocity.js You can see how to do that here: http://css-tricks.com/clever-uses-step-easing/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am trying to stay away from using a plugin/library if possible, but will bookmark this for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your code structure, I created a `.animateSteps()` function:

```
$(".window").hover(
    function () {
        $(".window").animateSteps(280,-280,20);
    },
    function () {
        $(".window").animateSteps(3080,280,20);
    }
);


$.fn.animateSteps = function(final,step,duration) {
    if(typeof t != "undefined") clearTimeout(t);
    var self = $(this);
    if(parseInt(self.css('background-position-y'))==final) return;
    self.css('background-position-y', '+='+step+'px');
    t=setTimeout(function(){self.animateSteps(final,step,duration);},duration);
}
```

It takes 3 parameters:

- `final`: the final position in pixels
- `step` : the number of pixels to increment at each step
- `duration` : the duration between 2 iterations

### JS Fiddle Demo